# expressjs - how to require multer in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, multer

i use [multer](/questions/tagged/multer) according to it's readme file in github
it's readme said call multer in [middleware](/questions/tagged/middleware) like this:

**app.js**

```
var multer = require('multer')
app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), function(req, res){})
```

but i defined my **function(req, res)** in another file - post.js - and my code in **app.js** looks like this:

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), post.new)
```

how can i **require** multer only on post.js, almost like this:

**post.js**

```
 var multer = require('multer')
 module.exports.new = function(req, res){
     //access to req.file
 }
```

**app.js**

```
 app.post('/upload', post.new)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways.

Firstly, you could expose `new` as an array:

```
module.exports.new = [upload.single('image'), function(req, res) {
    ...
}];
```

Secondly, you could use `multer` within your function:

```
var imageUpload = upload.single('image');

module.exports.new = function(req, res) {
    imageUpload(req, res, function(err) {
        // Put the rest of your code here
    });
};
```

In this second approach we're just invoking the `multer` middleware function ourselves, passing it our own function to use as the `next` callback. There's a little bit more information about doing this at https://github.com/expressjs/multer#error-handling though it describes the technique in a slightly different context.

Comment: exports.functionName = [upload.single('image'), (req, res) {
    ...
}];

Made my day sir @skirtle, thank you

Answer (score 2):

For MVC structure You can simply do this by :

```
function Uploader(req, res, next) {
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {

            cb(null, your_path);

        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, filename)
        }
    });

    var upload = multer({
        storage: storage
    });

    return upload;
}

module.exports = Uploader
```

In another file you can simply use

```
app.post('/upload', Uploader.single('image'), function(req, res){})
```

If you don't want to create function, you can do the following:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, upload_filePath)
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null,filename)
  }
})
var upload= multer({
   storage : upload
})

module.exports.upload=upload;
```

Both gives same result but using Function is more appropriate way.